# Can I use openwrt on non wireless machine?

Tags: networking, router, openwrt

I own tiny mini-itx pc, which I want to use as home router & server (samba, cups, torrent etc.). It dosen't have wireless card, whole network is wired only. Can I use OpenWRT x86 for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** But why would you? There should be no need to fit the whole system into 8 MB of memory. Just use a lightweight distribution like [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/). It offers much more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I choose OpenWRT because it's easy (fast) to setup and has GUI (I prefer network configuration with GUI than CLI)

Comment: OpenWrt's architecture has some severe restrictions to fit into most router's memory. I really advise you not to use it on a regular PC. A regular distribution is much better suited and can maximize your efficiency. Both power and performance-wise.

Comment: Actually it's Intel Atom 2-core. I will use OpenWRT x86 version, which, I think, is as good as any other Linux.